# How does JVM Clojure's implementation of Protcols work?

Tags: java, interface, clojure

The documentation on Clojure [protocols](http://clojure.org/protocols) states that a corresponding Java interface is generated for each protocol. However, the things which you can do with protocols (extending them to arbitrary types, etc.) don't seem like anything which have a straightforward implementation in terms of Java interfaces. How do protocols and protocol methods work internally? Why and how is a Java interface per protocol required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A brief examination of the Clojure platform source code reveals:

1. For each protocol method, there is a hashtable which maps from Java `Class` to the Clojure function which implements the protocol for that `Class`. (It's actually an instance of a custom class called `MethodImplCache`.)
2. When the dispatch function for a protocol method is called, it gets the `Class` of the first argument and does a lookup in the hashtable.
3. If it doesn't find anything, it walks the inheritance chain for the first argument, until it finds a superclass for which the lookup succeeds. Then it inserts the dispatch `Class` in the hashtable, so it can be found directly next time.
4. Additionally, any time a lookup succeeds, the most recently found `Class` and its corresponding method implementation are cached in an instance variable, and used to bypass the hash lookup if the dispatch `Class` is the same next time.
5. When protocols are extended to arbitrary Java classes, the generated interface does not come into play in any way. Calls to protocol methods are resolved using `MethodImplCache` as described above.
6. The generated interface **is** used when you use `reify` to get an instance of an anonymous class which extends a protocol, or if you use `deftype` or `defrecord` to make a new class which extends a protocol. In any of those cases, you will get back an object of a `Class` which implements the generated interface.
7. When the Clojure compiler emits JVM bytecode for a call to a protocol method, it inserts some bytecode which checks if the first argument is an instance of the generated interface. If it is, it uses an ordinary Java method call to the appropriate method of the interface. In that case, the protocol dispatch function which I described above is bypassed completely and never called.

This all seems to imply that when extended to arbitrary classes, protocol method calls should be slower than ordinary Clojure function calls. Performance when used with `reify`/`deftype`/`defrecord` should be much better if you extend the protocol inline, rather than doing so with a separate call to `extend-protocol` or `extend-type`.